# Firewall: Add command-line tool to rules (mosh-server)

Tags: homebrew, macos, firewall

How can I add a command line tool I've installed manually to the system firewall? The tool is [Mobile Shell (mosh)](https://mosh.mit.edu/) installed via the excellent [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/))?

Specifically, I want to add a rule for `/usr/local/bin/mosh-server` that allows incoming UDP traffic on 60001-60999.

I've tried using System Preference's Firewall pane and the "+" button, but I cannot seem to browse to `/usr`. I've configured Finder to display hidden and system files using [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), but that seemingly has no affect on the selection dialogue, which still hides `/usr`.

I've read a bit about using `ipfw`, but that's no longer available in Yosemite (v10.10). `pfctl` seems to be the replacement. I'll use these if I have to, but I'd much rather add an entry to the system firewall UI, so the change is discoverable.

Answer (score 1):

I knew I was being dumb: in the Finder dialog that pops up, press Shift+⌘+G and enter `/usr`. From there I can browse to the binary.

Turns out this is a completely ordinary Finder shortcut for "Go to folder".